# HUD tutorial for cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I've tried following this tutorial (http://www.raywenderlich.com/4666/how-to-create-a-hud-layer-with-cocos2d) however as you can probably tell I'm not using the tutorial for the same thing as them, but for an almost identical setup. I believe I've followed it step by step. However i get the error (location shown by arrows: <----) 'Unknown type name 'settingsMenu'' and 'expected a type' respectively:

mainMenu.h:

```
//  mainMenu.h


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "Constants.h"
#import "SceneManager.h"
#import "settingsMenu.h"



@interface mainMenu : CCLayer {  
    settingsMenu * _settings; <----
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL iPad;

+ (id)scene;
- (id)initWithsettingsMenu:(settingsMenu *)settings; <----

@end
```

mainMenu.m:

```
//  mainMenu.m

#import "mainMenu.h"  
#import "gameData.h"
#import "gameDataParser.h"
#import "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
#import "settingsMenu.h"

@implementation mainMenu

@synthesize iPad;

+ (id)scene {
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    settingsMenu *settings = [settingsMenu node];
    [scene addChild:settings z:1];
     mainMenu *menuLayer = [[[mainMenu alloc] initWithsettingsMenu:settings] autorelease];
     [scene addChild:menuLayer];

    return scene;
}
```

settingsMenu.h:

```
//  settingsMenu.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "Constants.h"
#import "SceneManager.h"

@interface settingsMenu: CCLayer {
    CCMenuItem *_musicOn;
    CCMenuItem *_musicOff;
    CCMenuItem *_invertControlsOn;
    CCMenuItem *_invertControlsOff;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL iPad;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL settings;

@end
```

settingsMenu.m:

```
//  settingsMenu.m


#import "settingsMenu.h"
#import "gameData.h"
#import "gameDataParser.h"
#import "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
#import "mainMenu.h"


@implementation settingsMenu

- (id)init{
    if( (self=[super init])) {

        // Determine Screen Size
        CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

        self.iPad = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad;

        if (self.iPad){
            CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"settingsiPad.png"];
            background.position = ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);
            [self addChild:background];
        }

        else if (screenSize.height > 490){
            CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"settingsiPhoneFive.png"];
            background.position = ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);
            [self addChild:background];
        }

        else{
             CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"settingsiPhone.png"];
             background.position = ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);
            [self addChild:background];
        }
     [self addButtons];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Thanks for your time! I don't think there's any need for posting any more code, but if there is anywhere else that might be causing this problem, please let me know and I'll post the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gameLayer .h: (I took out most of the unnecessary stuff)

```
//  GameLayer.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface GameLayer : CCLayer {
    CCLayer *HudLayer;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCLayer *HudLayer;

+(id)scene;
@end
```

Then in the .m  you

```
@synthesize HudLayer;
```

Then in the `init`,

```
//HUD Layer setup

        HudLayer = [[[CCLayer alloc] init] autorelease];
        [self addChild:HudLayer];
             //add stuff in the HUD here...


        CCMenuItem *Mainmenu = [[[CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"Main Menu" target:self selector:@selector(MainMenu:)] retain]autorelease];

        Mainmenu.position = ccp(size.width /2-Mainmenu.rect.size.width,size.height /2-Mainmenu.rect.size.height);
        CCMenu *Hudmenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems: Mainmenu, nil];
        [HudLayer addChild:Hudmenu];
    //End HUD Layer setup
```

Comment: I then get two Apple Mach-O linker errors...


Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_gameDataParser", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in settingsMenu.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Weirdest part is xCode is kind of recognising at as a class because it's colouring it blue, but as soon as I compile it throws up those errors :/

Comment: Well I'm not quite sure why you don't just have `_settings` be a CCLayer. I mean if its a HUD type setup.

Comment: Because that's what the tutorial says to do ;) I'm no expert on cocos2d... yet :P

Comment: Same boat here. But let me show you how I've implement my HUD.

Comment: Good to hear! Don't forget to check the question as answered